# How to get grandchildren from child(c# UNITY)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I get the grandchildren of children in unity

Here's my heirarchy structure

[image]

I tried doing this

```
public Transform[] trans;

trans = GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();

foreach(Transform gc in trans)
{
    //this could only get the first layer.
}
```

My script by the way is in `ScrollView` GameObject

EDIT:

```
Transform grid_gametable;
// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    sp = sv.GetComponent<SpringPanel>();
    if (sp == null) sp = sv.AddComponent<SpringPanel>();

    sp.target.x = 0;
    sp.target.y = 0;
    sp.target.z = 0;

    StartCoroutine("ItemCheck");

}


IEnumerator ItemCheck()
{
    grid_gametable = transform.Find("Grid_gametable");

    for (int i = 0; i < grid_gametable.childCount; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log("How many: " + grid_gametable);
    }
    yield return null;
}
```

It's weird that the count is not working .

Comment: 1.You have `GetComponentsInChildren` so you need to explain which object this script is attached to. 2.Explain which objects you want to get reference to

Comment: 1. It is attached in the `ScrollView` .

2. I want to get all those `Prefab Gamestables`

.

Comment: The title and comment in this question says "get grandchildren from child". Your edit says with the code says "count is not working". Which one is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the script is attached to ScrollView, you can use `transform.Find` to find the "Grid_gametable" child first. After this, loop through that "grid_gametable" child to get all of its "prefab_Gametable_baccarat" child objects.

```
Transform grid_gametable = transform.Find("Grid_gametable");

foreach (Transform gc in grid_gametable)
{
    Debug.Log(gc.name);
}
```

---

Also, "grid_gametable" is the first child of "ScrollView". You also can use `transform.GetChild(0)` instead of `transform.Find` to find "grid_gametable" then loop over its children.

```
Transform grid_gametable = transform.GetChild(0);

foreach (Transform gc in grid_gametable)
{
    Debug.Log(gc.name);
}
```

Comment: What's is not working? Don't say "It's not working" That doesn't help anyone. Note that if the screenshot in your question what your scene looks like and your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51076392/how-to-get-grandchildren-from-childc-unity/51076784?noredirect=1#comment89142087_51076392) is true then there is **no** reason why this answer shouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand exactly what you want, so I'm going to assume what you want to do is this: If you imagine hierarchy as a tree, you want to find each leaf of the tree? We can do this with a typical graph search. I've used breadth first search here.

```
public static List<Transform> FindAllLeaves(Transform transform)
{
    var transforms = new List<Transform>();
    var queue = new Queue<Transform>();

    queue.Enqueue(transform);

    while(queue.Count > 0)
    {
        var t = queue.Dequeue();
        if(transform.childCount > 0)
        {
            foreach (Transform child in t.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>())
            {
                queue.Enqueue(child);
            }
        } else
        {
            transforms.Add(t);
        }
    }
    return transforms;
}
```

Is this what you were trying to achieve?